# VBA on change event ruins the ListObjectTable on extending rows

Tags: vba, excel

My code works with a listobject.table and  is intended to allow editing prices and calculating discounts or vice versa... 
On entering the cell for editing it turns the formula therein into a value and pastes the formula in another column.

It works like a charm when the user is editing cells. But if the user tries to add rows to the listobject.table, the macro ruins the table. It adds a couple of columns and some headers are replaced.

Is it possible to make the macro somehow to disregard the operation of adding new rows or extending the range of data.table?

Here is the macro, thank you my friends for advice:

Private oListObj As ListObject

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Set oListObj = Worksheets("Quotation").ListObjects("tblProForma")

Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Not Intersect(Target, oListObj.ListColumns("Price").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Target.Formula = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, oListObj.ListColumns("Discount").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Target.Formula = Round(Target.Value, 5)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim PriceDiscountOffset As Integer: PriceDiscountOffset = ActiveSheet.Range("tblProForma[[#All],[Price]:[Discount]]").Columns.Count - 1

Set oListObj = Worksheets("Quotation").ListObjects("tblProForma")

Application.EnableEvents = True


    If Not Intersect(Target, oListObj.ListColumns("Price").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

    Target.Offset(0, PriceDiscountOffset).Formula = "=IF([@[Price]]<>"""", -([@[Price]]-[@[Pricelist]])/[@[Price]],"""")"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, oListObj.ListColumns("Discount").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Target.Offset(0, -PriceDiscountOffset).Formula = "=[@[Pricelist]]-([@[Pricelist]]*[@[Discount]])"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: how about wrapping a `If Target.Rows.Count = 1 and Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then ... End If` block around the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event. This way the code will only fire when a single cell is edited.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out.